# Using Math class to convert cosine into degrees

Tags: java, math

I don't know if I have a fundamental misunderstanding of sine, cosine and tangent or I have a misunderstanding of some of the Math class methods or I'm missing something else but I'm little confused.

I have a right triangle ABC with B = 90 degrees. AB is vertical, BC is flat and AC is the hypotenuse. The length value for  AB = 125 and AC = 150. I want to find the value of angle A.

[image]

I first try to find the cosine and then I want to convert the cosine to degrees.

```
double AB = 125;
double AC = 150;


double angleA = Math.cos(AB / AC);
double angleADegrees = Math.toDegrees(angleA);
println(angleADegrees);
```

The program as it's written returns 57.295. If i try it on my calculator I get a different answer. If I calculate on my calculator to find the cosine = 125/150 i get .8333. Cos^-1(.83333) = 33.5573. The strange thing 57 + 33 + 90 = 180. My program above somehow fnids the value for angle C instead of angle A. Am i calculating for cosine wrong or am I misusing  the methods from Math class? I don't know why my program does not return 33 which is what I believe to be the value of angle A.

Comment: I think you're backwards.  You want to use the arc-cosine if you're starting with a ratio.

Comment: @HotLicks I tried Math.acos instead of Math.cos and my program returned 90.

Comment: "public static double sin(double a)  Returns the trigonometric sine of an *angle*."  "public static double asin(double a)  Returns the arc sine of a value; the returned *angle* is in the range -pi/2 through pi/2."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert radians into degrees by multiplying it with `180/Math.PI`, Furthermore the inverse cosine (or cos^-1 like some textbooks denote this) is the `Math.acos` method (`a` standing for `arc`).

thus

```
double AB = 125;
double AC = 150;

double angleA = Math.acos(AB / AC);
println(angleA*180.0d/Math.PI);
```

will solve the problem.

In case you want to find angle `C`, you can calculate this by coding:

```
double angleCDeg = 90.0d-angleA*180.0d/Math.PI;//angle in degrees.
double angleC = angleC*Math.PI/180.0d;//angle in radians.
```

Comment: If i try your code my program return 90.0. Am I missing something else? I'm still looking up radians and I'm a little confused.

Comment: I've made a jdoodle http://jdoodle.com/a/4g and it returned the correct 33.xx degrees, You probably made another mistake.

Comment: you're right. I must have mistyped something before but when i copied and pasted it gave the right result. May I ask what the "d" means after 180 in the inside the println?

Comment: The postfix `d` means it's a double, `180.0f` means a float. I see now you want to compute the angle of C. You probably computed this by calculating `angleC = 90.0-angleA`. As you can see `angleA` is still in radians (it is only converted in the `println` statement). I've updated the answer.

Comment: The `d` isn't necessary - `180.0` is a `double`, without the `d`.  Also, since `angleA` is double, anything you multiply it by will be cast to `double` anyway.  So even `angleA*180/Math.PI` would give the right result.

Comment: That's true, but it has become second nature to write a `d` after each double. And sometimes it might matter, since for instance `400/180` gives another result than `400/180d`.

Comment: @Commusoft i had another quick question. I have to use GMath class instead of Java Math class and I still don't understand what exactly is happening. If i do double a = GMath.cosDegrees(AB/ AC); that will return .999. The GMath.cosDegrees method says it returns "the trigonometric cosine of an angle measured in degrees." In this case is .9999 a degree value or radian value? The GMath class does not have a Math.acos method so is it still possible to do the conversion?

Comment: @JessicaM. `cosDegree` is not the inverse cosine. The method expects an angle in degrees, ypuou provide the ratio between two lengths. I don't see the documentation of the GMath class, so I can't give a pointer to the correct method. Although I guess it must be something like `GMath.acosDegrees(AB/AC);`

Answer (score 1):

mathematically:

```
cos A = AB/AC

so cos A = 125 / 150

==> 

A = cos ^-1 ( 125 /150)
```

So from (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

```
double angleRad = Math.acos( AB / AC)
```

and

```
double angleDegrees  = angleRad * (180 / Math.PI)
```

Comment: That's C# I guess, In java methods start with a lower case.

Comment: @PreetSangha isn't cosine adjacent/hypotenuse so should it be 125/150 or 150/125?

Comment: Adjecent/long side so 125/150. The `acos` and `asin` are not defined outside the domain of `[-1:1]`. @JessicaM. is right, you should swap the sides. And probably perform a division as well (there is no method defined that takes two parameters).

Comment: @CommuSoft: Yes, there is a two-parameter function for computing angles; after computing `BC=Math.sqrt(AC*AC-AB*AB)` one could compute the angle via `angleA=atan2(BC,AB)`. Which would be overkill, since everything is positive and in the first quadrant.

Comment: @LutzL - Yep, atan2 is a most beauteous function, since it avoids divide by zero, is generally accurate in the boundary cases, and usually will take your values without additional manipulation (since you most often compute the angle of a point relative to the origin and you have the X and Y coordinates that plug right in).